# setHTTPMethod isn't working anymore?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

This is the code I've been using in IOS since I started programming in it. Though I stopped for the last year and now I return and its not posting anymore. In fact I checked the proxy and nothing is happening. I tried even putting it right under "[super viewDidLoad];" Did something change with Xcode 6 / iOS 8? Thank You :-) Ps. Sorry for my english.

```
NSString *post = @"car=geo";
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://thesitehere"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

Comment: Where's your code to actually fire the request? A request requires an operation to consume it.

Comment: I have it being control by a IBAction, I run a NSLog and I do get a reply. I can even change the button title fine. It just not sending out this request. Thank You

Comment: @MikeGoldsmith Please show your NSURLConnection code that uses this request.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You guys, I forgot the "NSURLConnection" I knew that its been a year. haha. 
Thanks Again.

```
NSURLConnection *myCon = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```